# Comment Python code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments

My Visual Studio Code comment Python code with `'''` instead of using `#` when I try to comment a block of code with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That’s the traditional way of “commenting out” multiple lines of text.

Comment: python interpret '''string''' as a string in python comment with #
¿There any way to comment code with visual studio with # python code?

Comment: I don’t use Visual Studio, so I have no idea.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 9):

For VS Code and Python,

- Select the block of code
- To Comment press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>
- To Uncomment press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>

Comment: is there a way to change this setup (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows environment this work for me :

- select block text
- press **CTRL + /**

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing specifically to to with Visual Studio, but a result of the python commenting styles. Generally, single line comments are done with the pound (or hash) symbol:

```
# This is a comment
```

In contrast, three quotation marks (either ''' or """) can be used to easily produce multi-line comments.

```
'''
This is also a comment.
However, this comment crosses multiple lines
'''
```

or

```
"""
This is yet another multiline comment
For long comments the quotation marks are much easier than # comments.
"""
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically, that's a multi-line string literal, not a comment. But the Python byte code compiler recognizes literals that are not assigned anywhere and either ignores them sort of like comments (if they're in the middle of the code) or stores them as docstrings (if they're at the top of a module, class, function or method).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at [KINDA CODE](https://www.kindacode.com/article/vs-code-how-to-comment-out-a-block-of-python-code/).

1. Select the block of code.
2. Press Ctrl + K
3. Press Ctrl + C